# Nothings working in my nested conditionals using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

So Im learning jQuery at the moment, and have to make a Loan calculator based on choices, as well as validate enteries, then output a result.

l wanted to make sure you guys knew what I was trying to do, so I have here a flow chart of what is supposed to happen: http://i59.tinypic.com/8z02sh.jpg

Problem is I dont know how to do this is Jquery. I asked a question earlier, got some feedback. None of the code people provided to outright fix my code, actually worked. I took a guy named "Parody"s work, and rewrote my code. I am no longer getting errors, and what im doing now makes sense to me. Problem is, when i input a number, and click the button, nothing happens. So here's my code so far.

Thanks ahead of time.

http://jsfiddle.net/mL74efjd/1/

HTML -

```
<h1>Loan Calc</h1>
<form id="salaryForm" name="salaryForm2" method="Post" action="javascript:void(0)">
<label for="salary">Enter your annual salary</label>
<input type="text" name="salary" id="salary">

</form>


<form id="creditform" name="creditForm" method="Post" action="javascript:void(0)">
<p>Please select your Credit Score</p>
<p><input type="radio" name="radio" id="over1" value="0">
<label for="over1">Over 600</label></p>
<p><input checked type="radio" name="radio" id="under1" value="0">
<label for="under1">Under 600</label></p>
</form>


<p> How long have you worked at your current job? </p>
<input class="job" id="job1" name="job" type="radio" value="0">
<label for="job1">I have worked at my current job over 1 year.</label><br>
<br/>
<input checked class="job" id="job2" name="job" type="radio" value="0">
<label for="job2">I have worked at my current job less than 1 year.</label><br>

</form>

<input type="button" id="check" name="check" value="Check">
<div id="message"></div>
```

JS-

```
$('#check').click(function()
{
  var salary;
  var isValid = $('#salaryForm').validate().form();
  // if validation passes, display a message
  if (isValid)
  {

    if (salary < 40000)
    {
      if ($('#over1').is(':checked'))
      {
        if ($('#job1').is(':checked'))
        {
          $('#message').html("Loan Approved.")
        }
        else {
          $('#message').html("Loan Denied.")
        }
      }
      else 
      {
        $('#message').html("Loan Denied.")
      }
    }
    else if (salary >= 40000)
    {
      if ($('#under1').is(':checked'))
      {
        if ($('#job2').is(':checked'))
        {
          $('#message').html("Loan denied.")
        }
        else 
        {
          if ($('#job1').is(':checked'))
            $('#message').html("Loan Approved.")
        }
      }else 
        {
          $('#message').html("Loan Approved.")
        }
      }
    }
});


// form validation
$.validator.setDefaults({
        errorElement: "span",
        errorClass: "form_error",
        errorPlacement: function(error, element){
            error.insertAfter(element)
        }
    });

    $.extend($.validator.messages,{
        required: "* Required field"
    });

$('#salaryForm').validate(
{
  rules:
  {
    salary:
    {
      required: true,
      digits: true,
      range: [1, 1000000]
    }
  }

});
```

Comment: Have you added jquery library in your code? I can't see added jquery library and validator library in you provided fiddle.

Comment: Have you included [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) and [jQuery-validation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/) libraries?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mL74efjd/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

variable salary is not initiailized inside click method. Put--

```
var salary=$("#salary").val();
```

Also in fiddle jquery and jquery-validation library are not included

Answer (score 1):

I think you haven't added jQuery validation libraries. The line

```
 $('#salaryForm').validate().form();
```

will give error as validate() method doesnt exist.

So add validation libraries in your html and assign a value to the salary variable.

```
var salary = $("#salary").val();
```

It will work fine then.